# How to turn on .NET 6 Web Api Parameter binding by default for complex types?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Here is my problem. I migrated from ASP.NET Framework 4.7 WEB API to .NET 6 (Core). I did this by creating a new project using the Web API template and copying my classes over, and changing controller type to ControllerBase and response type to IActionResult.  I'm using Postman to post a simple JSON object to my method, and now I only get values in the properties of my complex object ("Form")) if I explicitly add [FromBody] in front of the parameter declaration. If I don't add that my object is not null but none of the properties have values. I could spend some hours adding this in to all my methods but this has a bad smell to me because the Microsoft documentation says that by default WebAPI should perform parameter binding to the complex object and JSON is supported by default. This makes me concerned something else in my app is broken or missing.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/v3/{appid}/chat/rooms/{roomid}/events/{eventid}/react")]
public IActionResult PostReaction(string appid, string roomid, string eventid, ReactionFormModel Form)
{
       ...  // Form is not null but all fields have null value
}
```

Sample of my JSON input:

```
{
    "userid": "alfgivemefour",
    "reaction": "like",
    "reacted": "true"
}
```

I am referencing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson nuget package and Newtonsoft.Json package (althought it seems to make no difference if its there or not).

This is my program.cs:

```
// How to introduce NLog support: https://medium.com/projectwt/nlog-with-ilogger-in-net-6-0-web-api-fb7072d8ac6c
using NLog;
using NLog.Web;
using talkapi.Common.Caching;
using talkapi.Common.Config;
using talkapixp.Plumbing;

// Create an instance of the logger as per above article on NLogger
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
IWebHostEnvironment environment = builder.Environment;
logger.Debug("[Program] init main using environment: " + environment.EnvironmentName);
bool isDevelopment = environment.IsDevelopment();

var configuration = builder.Configuration
                .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)                
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

// Insert configuration provider that works with appsettings.{env}.json
ConfigManager.SetProvider(new ConfigProviderNetCore(configuration) as IConfigProvider);

// Cache Manager needs a provider from the database
CacheManager.SetCacheProvider(talkapi.Database.Caching.Factory.GetProvider());

// NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
builder.Host.UseNLog();

// Add JSON support when posting to web api so complex objects will deserialize
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

//other classes that need the logger via dependency injection
builder.Services.AddTransient<LogHelper>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Adds MVC support
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I think it should be [HttpGet].  Controllers can be use at both client and server.  So at client you Post request and get response.  At server you get request and post response.

Comment: I created a new template (.net 6 web api), and then tried several requests according to your description, all of which can successfully receive parameters: `public IActionResult PostReaction( string appid,  string roomid,  string eventid, [FromBody] ReactionFormModel Form)`, `public IActionResult PostReaction( string appid,  string roomid,  string eventid, ReactionFormModel Form)`, `public IActionResult PostReaction( [FromRoute]string appid,  [FromRoute]string roomid,  [FromRoute]string eventid, [FromBody] ReactionFormModel Form)`.

Comment: Can you provide more details?